# What's the difference between a button with IsDefault and IsDefaulted?

Tags: wpf

Can anyone explain me better?

I didn't understand too much just reading the documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you set `IsDefault` to true, button will become the default button for the window i.e. if ENTER key is pressed when the current focus is not on any focusable control that accepts ENTER Key the button click event will be triggerred. If button click event can be triggered due to this default action then `IsDefaulted` will be true else it will be false. That means if the Default button has focus in this case `IsDefaulted` will be false as event will not be triggered by default.

`IsDefaulted` is readonly property which only tells if the button can be clicked by default at present state of focus i.e. the button click event can be triggered on ENTER press when Button did not has the focus. IsDefault we can set to true if we want that button should have this default behaviour i.e. when ENTER key is pressed and even button was not in focus button click should be triggered. We set IsDefault. IsDefault once set to true will remain true but IsDefaulted will change its value depending on which control currently has focus.

Comment: sorry, I still didnt understand. Can you give me another example?

Comment: oh, great. Thanks. I will set this as the answer because I prefered this explanation.

Answer (score 10):

`IsDefault` determines whether the button is the "default" button for the Window.  [`IsDefaulted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.isdefaulted.aspx) will be `true` if `IsDefault` is true **and** the current control with focus doesn't accept an ENTER keypress.

In general, if `IsDefaulted` is true, it means pressing enter will trigger that button at that point in time.

Comment: sorry, I still see no difference at what you said. What you said about IsDefaulted is the same for IsDefault.

"In general, if IsDefaulted is true, it means pressing enter will trigger that button at that point in time.".

But thanks for trying to help. Can you explain me this better?

Comment: @Seva `IsDefault` can be true if the focus is in a RichTextBox.  In that case, pressing Enter will get "swallowed" by the RTB, and the window won't close.  Since RTB has focus, `IsDefault` will be true, but `IsDefaulted` will be false.  As soon as you change the focus to something else that doesn't use ENTER, such as a checkbox, then `IsDefaulted` will become true, because pressing ENTER *at that point in time* will trigger the close behavior.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Once you set `IsDefault = "True"` for a button, that button click event will be activated whenever you press `Enter key` anywhere in the form.

**Note:**
If you are inside a control which has attribute `AcceptsReturn = "True"`
Ex: Multiline textbox or listbox, then `Enter key` will only insert new line and wont activate the default button rather you need to do a `Ctrl + Enter key` to activate default button